# Find and copy certain values in cells

Tags: vba, excel

I have a column with filenames of the following format:
somenumber_sometext_1_100_AA
These filenames are in column A. I need to scan each filename in each cell and copy the number 1 and paste it into column B and copy the number 100 and paste it in column C, all of the same row as the filename. I then want to repeat for the next cell down in column A.
Help would be appreciated!

Comment: Do you mean you have strings of this format "www_xxx_yyy_zzz_AA", where www, xxx, yyy, and zzz are numbers? And you just want yyy and zzz?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As this was tagged with VBA, I will give a simple vba macro solution.

The easiest way is to define a VBA function called splitText(test,delim, n) , which will split text by a delimiter, and get the nth column. This is so commonly needed, I wish they'd just make it standard.

```
Function splitText(txt As String, delim As String, n As Integer)
    splitText = split(txt, delim)(n)
End Function
```

Then, if the string is A1, put this in B1:

```
=splitText(A1,"_",2)
```

And this in C1:

```
=splitText(A1,"_",3)
```

Comment: I feel like this should work. How would I include this in my current VBA code? What should I declare splitText As? Thank You!

Comment: Just copy the above function text into a module under the visual basic developer, and it should work. You can have a "as string" qualifier at the end of the declaration, but its not necessary.

Comment: Got it. So I can I call that macro from another module?

Comment: Yes, you can, though using "split(text,delim)" is better from pure VBA. This function is really just a wrapper around the standard VBA split function, so it can be used as an excel formual function.

Comment: I think I know why it's not working. So I inserted the function in a module and in my main macro I did the following: Range(Cells(1, 2), Cells(lastRownum + 1, 2)).Formula = "=splitText(A1,"_",2)" When the quotation marks " are there before and after the underscore, I get an error saying that the underscore is an invalid character.

Comment: Tyler Peryea I had to add Chr(34) for the quotation marks inside my formula, but your code works, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

With:

3141543_junktext_4563_10098_ZZ

in cell **A1,** in **B1** enter:

```
=TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE($A1,"_",REPT(" ",999)),COLUMNS($A:C)*999-998,999))
```

and in **C1** enter:

```
=TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE($A1,"_",REPT(" ",999)),COLUMNS($A:D)*999-998,999))
```

To display *4563* and *10098*

Comment: This sounds like an [excel-formula] version of Split :) Good to know.

Comment: @Gary's Student I tried putting this as a formula in my VBA code, but it doesn't allow me. I get compile errors for invalid characters.

Comment: Do you need **;** in place of **,**

Comment: @Gary's Student So I did the following: Range(Cells(1, 2), Cells(lastRownum + 1, 2)).Formula = "=TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE($A2,"_",REPT(" ",999)),COLUMNS($A:C)*999-998,999))" where I wrapped your code in quotations marks. I can't run the code. I can run it if I remove the quotation marks inside SUBSTITUTE and REPT, but obviously that doesn't work. Any suggestions?

Comment: You need to double-up on the internal double-quotes!

Comment: @Gary's Student Nevermind, I had to add Chr(34) for the quotation marks, but your code works, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If each section is delimited (ie in the example by `_`) then Text to Columns with that as the delimiter and then deleting the last and the first two columns may be convenient.

(But copy into a new column first or you will lose your source data.)

Comment: This is by far the easiest way to do this. Though it's not exactly "programmatic". Don't know if question asker needs a dynamic update ...